# Upgrade 9.10 to 10.04

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, update-manager, 9.10

We have Karmic Koala on our workstation.

When we tried upgrading using Update Manager, the window froze (turned black and white) and we had to "Force Quit".

We used the command-line "sudo do-release-upgrade -d", it shows "Checking new ubuntu release" without any further output.

Both methods did not work for about 2-3 hrs. Should we have tried longer?
If not, how do we proceed now?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu **9.10** (Koala) is no longer supported, and so upgrading from 9.10 to **10.04 LTS** is also not supported.

---

Once you have your data and settings backed-up, you should do a **fresh** install of Ubuntu on your *workstation*. There may be initial issues with drivers, but this should mostly be resolved by doing an update.

Once you have **10.04 LTS** working, then *try out* (but do **not** immediately install) Ubuntu **12.04 LTS**. This may also work on your PC, but may not be quite as fast.

I have successfully run both **10.04 LTS** and **12.04 LTS** on an HP Mini netbook (Atom processor, 1GB RAM) or ex-corporate desktops (P4 2.8GHz, 1GB RAM).

---

**UPDATE:**

Any attempt to upgrade is potentially a **high risk** to any data (and settings) on the PC. Therefore, the data (and settings) **must** first be *backed-up*.

*As you have already identified issues with attempting to upgrade, it seemed better advice to suggest that you instead do a **new install**.*

**Note:** Any inconvenience to yourself and other users also needs to be weighed against the potential loss of data, and likely failure, of the upgrade attempt.

Comment: +1,  9.10 (Koala) is no longer supported, and so upgrading from 9.10 to 12.04 LTS is also not supported. I wasn't aware that unsupported versions are not upgradable.

Comment: The issue being that any upgrade problems may directly relate to behavior of the *unsupported* platform you are updating from. *The upgrade can be attempted, but lacks 'support'.*

Comment: Thank you. But we do not want a fresh installation, since we have large amount of data and user accounts on our workstation as we are not the only ones using it. A fresh installation might jeopardize their data too. Is there any other way?

Comment: We are thinking of using clonezilla for backup. We are using it for the first time.Does the softare include backup for settings like userids etc. too